# How to get the contact group id or name?

Tags: java, android

I can't get the group name under which the contact is stored. I can get whether it is added in any group as boolean value( IN_VISIBLE_GROUP).I have no idea how to get the group name or id.

```
     ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
     while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {

                 id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                String group = cur
                .getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP));
```

i have tried using ContactsContract.Groups and ContactsContract.Groups and ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership but that is not the solution.

Comment: Normaly, you would use the [ContactsContract.Groups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html)-class. Why does it not work for you?

Comment: @Lukas i used String g = cur
     .getString(cur1
       .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE)); but returns the same BaseColumns._ID.Any snippet code to get using ContactsContract.Groups please..

Comment: You could check the basic Android-Contact app, who's source code can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/tree/master/src/com/android/contacts)

Comment: @Lukas thanks but i get the group name still getting errors

Answer (score 1):

This is a full version of how to get the group id by its `title`. Basically it iterates `all groups` and compare titles to find its `id`.

```
private String getGroupId(String groupTitle) {
   Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{ContactsContract.Groups._ID,ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE}, null, null, null);       
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int len = cursor.getCount();

    String groupId = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Groups._ID));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Groups.TITLE));

        if (title.equals(groupTitle)) {
            groupId = id;
            break;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return groupId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
 ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
```

to

```
 Uri groupURI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;


Cursor cur = cr.query(groupURI , null, null, null, null);


// Now you can get group ID from cursor

String groupRowId =  cur.getString   (cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Integer getGroupId(String groupTitle) {

        String[] PROJECTION = {ContactsContract.Groups._ID};
        String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + "=?";

        try (Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, new String[]{groupTitle}, null)) {

                if (cursor.getCount()>0){
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    Integer id= cursor.getInt(0);
                    return id;
                }else
                    return 0;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).